# How to properly generate walls simulating perspective around stone in a cave-like level made of squares?

Tags: 2d, procedural-generation, level-design, levels, perspective

Long story short. My levels tiles currently look like this:

[image: currently]

And i want them to look like this:

[image]

My levels are designed as 400x400 squares of proceduraly generated 0's and 1's, 0 representing dirt(walkable by player), 1 represeting stone(impenetrable).
Game itself looks a lot like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgs1d.png)**.

At first, my method was to run another loop - after generating the world that **replaced stone** tiles, depending on directions of empty tiles were, with wall. The method doesn't work so bad up to the point where there are 1 wide walls sticking out, which are impossible for it to convert, check picture:

[image]

As you can see, in my method, the wall is an another texture, taking one tile itself.
I can't replace air with walls, as that could possibly obstruct a passage. It basically fails every time there are 3 or more dirt tiles directly next to it.

This is the place at which i wondered if i chose the right method or if i should change the whole design for the walls, if so - to what? Should i create some textures for the 1-wides alone? Or maybe i shouldn't generate 1-wides at all? How do games generally deal with this?

I've looked for the answer to my problem, and haven't found it. Probably because it's hard for me to word it(sorry for messy post).

Comment: Can you make it more visually clear what is wrong with your approach? I don't get your problem.

Comment: You should use an autotiling algorithm to display the walls. (See http://www.saltgames.com/2010/a-bitwise-method-for-applying-tilemaps/) The example stand for a platformer, but i'm personnaly using it to display caves similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Tinco Yeah, not strange, it was very hard to word for me. Trying to make it simpler: I can't figure out the proper way to create walling around stone in a level.

Comment: @Khopa That is a brilliant link! Thank you, i will probably use it as game develops, answer provided below by Mario fits me _fine_ for what i need now, but the site you provided answers my problem ultimately, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might not be ideal or the most performant option depending on your actual use case, you could just create a single "3d tile" that is actually bigger than your real tile (due to having the 3d part attached):

[image: 3D tile example]

While the tile size would be 32 × 32 pixels, this tile image is actually 40 × 40 pixels big (the fake depth is 8 pixels in every direction).

When rendering, you just render the tiles from left to right, top to bottom, with the tile's delta (in this example 32 pixels).

For example, to render a "T", you'd render the tiles in the following order:

[image: 3D tiles examples]

Comment: I really like your idea! That is brilliantly simplistic. I think i'll use it, because it really does all i need it to, for now. Thanks for the answer!